# lme4 non-linear modelling with missing values

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, growth-model

I am using *lme4* R package for modelling growth curves (ref: Mirman, Daniel, 2017). The code below shows an example suggested in the book about modelling non-linear growth curve (GC) models, the data is available [here](http://www.danmirman.org/gca/WordLearnEx.txt). My question is, why does the curve loose its smoothness when modelled using data with missing values (as in Fig 2)? Th multilevel GC regression equations handle missing values, so I do not understand the zig-zag behaviour of the curve. The same is observed if I used linear modelling as well. I am new to mixed models, and any help/pointers would be much appreciated.

```
t <- poly(unique(WordLearnEx$Block), 2)
WordLearnEx[,paste("ot", 1:2, sep="")] <-
  t[WordLearnEx$Block, 1:2]
df <- WordLearnEx
df[sample(560, 100),]$Accuracy <- NA


# model without missing values
m.wl <- lmer(Accuracy ~ ot1 + ot2 + (ot1 + ot2| Subject),
               data=WordLearnEx, REML=FALSE)

# model with missing values
m.df <- lmer(Accuracy ~ ot1 + ot2 + (ot1 + ot2| Subject),
               data=df, REML=FALSE)


# plot model fitted with all values
ggplot(WordLearnEx, aes(Block, Accuracy)) +
  stat_summary(aes(y=fitted(m.wl)), fun.y=mean,
               geom="line", size=1) +
  stat_summary(fun.data=mean_se,geom="pointrange",size=1)+
  theme_bw(base_size=10) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0.5, 1.0)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=1:10)
```

[image]

```
# plot model with fitted missing values
    ggplot(df[!is.na(df$Accuracy),], aes(Block, Accuracy)) +
      stat_summary(aes(y=fitted(m.df)), fun.y=mean,
                   geom="line", size=1) +
      stat_summary(fun.data=mean_se,geom="pointrange",size=1)+
      theme_bw(base_size=10) +
      coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0.5, 1.0)) +
      scale_x_continuous(breaks=1:10)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The linear mixed model indeed appropriately accounts for missing at random missing data, given that you have also appropriately/flexibly specified the covariance structure.

As far as I can see in your code you produce the fitted values from the model per subject and you average them. Hence, in the second figure, you do not account for the imputation that the model implicitly does. It would be more appropriate to compare the average longitudinal profiles from the two models, produced by, e.g., the **effects** package.